# Inheritance in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, inheritance

I am using node.js and programming based on express.js. I have tried to use `util.inherits` to implement inheritance in JavaScript. What I've tried is as follows:

```
//request.js
function Request() {
    this.target = 'old';
    console.log('Request Target: ' + this.target);
}

Request.prototype.target = undefined;
Request.prototype.process = function(callback) {
    if (this.target === 'new')
       return true;

    return false;
}

module.exports = Request;

//create.js
function Create() {
    Create.super_.call(this);
    this.target = 'new';
}

util.inherits(Create, Request);

Create.prototype.process = function(callback) {
    if (Create.super_.prototype.process.call(this, callback)) {
        return callback({ message: "Target is 'new'" });
    } else {
        return callback({ message: "Target is not 'new'" });
    }
}

module.exports = Create;

//main.js
var create = new (require('./create'))();
create.process(function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
});
```

My scenario is :

I have `Request` as base class and `Create` as child class. Request has field `target` that initialize `old` in `Request` constructor.

Now, I create `Create` class object which first call `Request` constructor and then initialize `target` field with `new`. When I call process function of `Create`, I expect to get message of `target is 'new'` but it returns another!

I searched similar threads for this, but all are what i tried! Can any one explain what was wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`util.inherits` has really awkward `super_`... anyway, this should work:

```
 Create.super_.prototype.process.call(this, callback);
```

But really,

```
 var super_ = Request.prototype;
```

And then the syntax becomes almost convenient:

```
 super_.process.call(this, callback);
```